# Firebase Update with Where Clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a flutter app. I would like to do the **equivalent of an SQL Update with a Where Clause**. This is my current working solution:

```
Future<void> updateWhere(String valueForWhere, String valueToUpdate) async {
  try {
    List<ObjectToUpdate> items;
    var query = await Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionName')
      .where(ObjectToUpdate.field1, isEqualTo: valueForWhere)
      .getDocuments();

    if (query.documents.isEmpty)
      return;
    else {
      items = query.documents.map((item) => ObjectToUpdate.deserialize(item.data, item.documentID)).toList();
    }

    for(var item in items) {
      item.field2 = valueToUpdate;
      Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionName')
        .document(item.uid)
        .updateData(item.serialize());
    }
  } 
  catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

This feels very roundabout as I have to **deserialize, modify, serialize, and update each object individually.**

Is there a simpler, more efficient way to do this? Or maybe some way I can optimize my current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're doing the right thing.  Firestore offers no equivalent of "update where" that you find in SQL.

Comment: And there's no way to optimize this method?

Comment: Nope, you have to read, modify in memory, and write each document.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "where" clause to fetch the documents you wish to update.
2. Get the document ID of each document you fetched.
3. Now, use the same document IDs to update the corresponding documents with new data.

This does the same job as "where - update", but in two separate steps.